# Assign function to UIScrollView when scrolling (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` I've added in `Interface Builder`. I want to have scrollView functions so I can detect if it's been scrolled up or down. My scroll view is attached with an `IBOutlet` called "mainScroll." Here is my code:

```
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0
@IBOutlet weak var mainScroll: UIScrollView!

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = mainScroll.contentOffset.y
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset < mainScroll.contentOffset.y) {
        // did move up
        print("Did Move Up")
    } else if (self.lastContentOffset > mainScroll.contentOffset.y) {
        // did move down
        print("Did Move Down")
    } else {
        // didn't move
    }
}
```

I've added `UIScrollViewDelegate` to my class. I have a feeling I'm not using the scrollView delegate callbacks properly. How can I take these functions and assign them to my "mainScroll"?

Comment: You need to connect the scroll view's delegate in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew I was missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need this in `viewDidLoad`

```
mainScroll.delegate = self
```